# Call to a member function check_if_image_exist() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm wondering whats wrong with my code why it is throwing me this error "Call to a member function check_if_image_exist() on a non-object D:\xampp\htdocs\project-001\application\controllers\c_userHome.php on line 48"

I have the same code with my other functions but the others works fine.. Im smashing my head with this error :(

This is in my controller:

```
        //check if dir has image
        $this->load->library('image_checker');
        $this->image_checker->check_if_image_exist(); //this is line 48
```

This is in my library which i call:

```
class Image_checker extends CI_Controller {

var $userfile_path;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->userfile_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../userfiles/');
}

public function check_if_image_exist()
{
        $user = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $dir = $this->userfile_path;

        $handle = opendir($dir);

        while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
             if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
                $file_list[] = $file;
             }
        }
        closedir($handle);

    return $file_list;
}
```

}

Thanks in Advance!
-Darryl

Comment: `$this->image_checker` is probably null... if that `load->library` thing is supposed to set it, it looks like it's failing.

Comment: image_checker vs Image_checker ? **I**

Comment: @Mark, yes you're right its probably null according to the error. and I wonder why the load->library thing is failing to load that obj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that seems to be your controller, since you are extending `CI_Controller`,
so change:

```
class Image_checker extends CI_Controller {
...
```

to

```
class Image_checker {
...
```

See more: [Codeigniter Custom Libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Comment: I have other obj which I put extends CI_controller, the same as what I did there above and it works fine. This is the only Obj & its function that throws me an error. I wonder why. I use extends CI_Controller so I can use other defined variables there, would it be just fine?

Comment: @user2036472 thats not the way you define libraries in CI, you can always pass in the controller-side defined variables to libraries without need to extend CI_Controller in libraries, pls have a look at CI user guide for detailed info

Comment: okay for now I think I should really look to it. thank you for replying to my question I really appreciate it :)